# Solspace Freeform 500 Internal Sever Error when Composer Template used

Tags: solspace-freeform, composer-template

Well, I'm getting 500 Internal Server Error when Composer Template used.

Composer Template looks like:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ff_composer * {
-webkit-box-sizing : border-box;
-moz-box-sizing : border-box;
box-sizing : border-box;
}
.ff_composer .line,
.ff_composer .line:last-child,
.ff_composer .last_unit{overflow:hidden;}
.ff_composer .unit{float:left; padding:10px;}
.ff_composer .unit_right{float:right;}
.ff_composer .size1of1{float:none;}
.ff_composer .size1of2{width:50%;}
.ff_composer .size1of3{width:33.33333%;}
.ff_composer .size2of3{width:66.66666%;}
.ff_composer .size1of4{width:25%;}
.ff_composer .size3of4{width:75%;}
.ff_composer .line:last-child,
.ff_composer .last_unit{float:none;width:auto;}
.ff_composer p,
.ff_composer h1,
.ff_composer h2,
.ff_composer h3,
.ff_composer h4,
.ff_composer h5,
.ff_composer h6 {margin-top: 0;}
.ff_composer .required_item {margin-left: 4px; color:red;}
.ff_composer textarea,
.ff_composer input[type="text"],
.ff_composer input[type="email"],
.ff_composer input[type="url"],
.ff_composer input[type="number"],
.ff_composer input[type="password"],
.ff_composer input[type="search"] {width: 75%;}
.ff_composer ul.dynamic_recipients {list-style: none; padding:0;}
.ff_composer .field_label {font-weight: bold;}
</style>
{exp:freeform:composer
form_name="contact-us"
composer_template_name="contact"
return="contact_us/thank_you"
}
<div class="ff_composer">
{composer:page}
{composer:rows}
<div class="line">
{composer:columns}
<div class="unit size1of{composer:column_total}">
{if composer:field_total == 0}

{/if}
{composer:fields}
{if composer:field_label}
{if composer:field_type == 'nonfield_captcha'}
{if freeform:captcha}
<p>
<strong>{composer:field_label}</strong>
</p>
{/if}
{if:else}
<label class="field_label" {if composer:field_name != ''}for="freeform_{composer:field_name}"{/if}>
{composer:field_label}{if composer:field_required}<span class="required_item">*</span>{/if}
</label>
{/if}
{/if}
{if composer:field_output}
{if composer:field_type == 'nonfield_title'}
<h2>{composer:field_output}</h2>
{if:elseif composer:field_type == 'nonfield_captcha'}
{if freeform:captcha}
{freeform:captcha}<br />
<input type="text" name="captcha" value=""
size="20" maxlength="20" style="width:140px;" />
{/if}
{if:else}
<p>{composer:field_output}</p>
{/if}
{/if}
{/composer:fields}
</div>
{/composer:columns}
</div>
{/composer:rows}
{/composer:page}
</div>
```

Code above is similar to code from documentation example.

Any clue what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example from their documentation is for a "free" Freefrom version or full form inclusion into EE template

In this case all Freeform parameters must be stored using Template Params instead of creating code in the Composer Template.